# joining two tables in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to join two tables in oracle sql but I cant seem to get it to work. The below sql is what I have so far. Cartype is in the vehicle table and price is in the purchase table. The key they have in common is ID. Can someone tell me whats wrong and provide a possible fix?

```
SELECT cartype, price
FROM VEHICLE547896
INNER JOIN PURCHASE547896
ON ID = ID
```

By the way I understand this question has been asked before but I'm still confused.

Comment: Just saying you can't get it to work isn't helpful - what is wrong? Do you get an error? Incorrect results? Also look at your query again; if both tables have a column called just ID, which table's column do you think is being referred to on each side of `ON ID = ID`?

Comment: You want to say that the ID of VEHICLE must be equal to the ID of PURCHASE? Are you sure?

Comment: Are your tables really called VEHICLE547896 and PURCHASE547896? Seems more like some kind of vehicle and purchase id's.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean? my tables really are called VEHICLE547896 and PURCHASE547896

Comment: Just very peculiar table names. How come you chose those names?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cartype, price
FROM VEHICLE547896 a
INNER JOIN PURCHASE547896 b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: thanks just tried this an it worked fine, however when I added ID to the select statement it said column ambiguously defined. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You need to mention the table name from which column is being picked else it gets confused from which table the column will be picked as their names are same in both.

Comment: SELECT cartype, price,a.id,b.id
    FROM VEHICLE547896 a
   INNER JOIN PURCHASE547896 b
   ON a.ID = b.ID

Comment: Because the query wants to display the ID column but there are two possibilities for that - The vehicle ID or the purchase ID. Prefix the column in the select with the table alias, i.e. a.id OR b.id

Comment: I'd use v and p as table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You need better understanding of table relationships.

Verify the equivalent of `ID` in `VEHICLE547896` when it's saved to `PURCHASE547896` table.

Is it `VehicleID`? `Vehicle_ID`? Or something like that. Because the `ID` in `PURCHASE547896` is for sure, the `ID` of the purchase, and not the vehicle.

```
SELECT cartype, price
FROM VEHICLE547896 AS v
INNER JOIN PURCHASE547896 AS p
ON v.ID = p.VehicleID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have columns with the same name then you also need to name the table before it

```
SELECT VEHICLE547896.cartype, PURCHASE547896.price
FROM VEHICLE547896
INNER JOIN PURCHASE547896 ON PURCHASE547896.ID = VEHICLE547896.ID
```